# Confusion Matrix Detailed Explanation of Dataset

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, classification, confusion-matrix

```
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, ['A.csv','B1.csv','B2.csv','B3.csv', 'C1.csv', 'C2.csv','C3.csv']))
```

As shown above, I used multiple datasets to train and test classification supervised ML models.

```
classes = ['Good','Bad']
def plot_confusionmatrix(prediction,real,dom):
    print(f'{dom} Confusion matrix')
    cf = confusion_matrix(prediction,real)
    sns.heatmap(cf,annot=True,yticklabels=classes
               ,xticklabels=classes,cmap='Blues', fmt='g')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

[image]

I wanted to ask if instead of showing the confusion matrix among the entire testing set, how can I focus only on those samples coming from the A dataset?
I am interested in seeing how these samples are classified.

Edit: As suggested, I added a column for each dataset and then I merged them.

```
A['Dataset'] = "A"
B1['Dataset'] = "B1"
B2['Dataset'] = "B2"
B3['Dataset'] = "B3"
C1['Dataset'] = "C1"
C2['Dataset'] = "C2"
C3['Dataset'] = "C3"
```

Solution:

```
df_train, df_test= train_test_split(df, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 42)
X_train = df_train.drop(['Label', 'Dataset'], axis=1)
y_train = df_train['Label']
X_test = df_test.drop(['Label', 'Dataset'], axis=1)
y_test = df_test['Label']

rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)
rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = rfc.predict(X_test)

for dataset_name in ['A']:
  dataset_df_test = df_test[df_test['Dataset'] == dataset_name]
  dataset_y_test = y_test.iloc[dataset_df_test.index]
  dataset_y_pred = y_pred[dataset_df_test.index]

  plot_confusionmatrix(dataset_y_pred, dataset_y_test, dom='Test')
```

Comment: It is impossible if you don't make a distinction before merging all the datasets. Create a column after reading the dataset indicating the dataset name and then merge. @linuxpanther

Comment: You may need to tag the datasets with some tagging columns or method, so after merging you can check the confusion matrix with the tagged column.

Comment: @linuxpanther Exactly as Mtaly describes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is no other way except plotting confusion matrix for each subset separately. It must be easy to do in your case by iterating through all dataset names, selecting corresponding rows from `y_test_DT_predicted` and `y_test` for each dataset and using selected values in `plot_confusionmatrix` call. Don't forget to manage multiple subplots in `plt` and call `plt.show()` once at the end of the loop.

Comment: That is a bit confusing for me. "Selecting corresponding rows from y_test_DT_predicted and y_test for each dataset and using selected values in plot_confusionmatrix"
Can you please explain here again?

Comment: I can try. I don't know what the type of y_test_DT_predicted and y_test though. Take a look at this gist (the code is not working, it's just an example of the logic): https://gist.github.com/serhii-maksymenko/bcbb004ba2bd13b9b37e670a1ac32f29

Comment: dataset_y_test = y_test.iloc[dataset_df_test.index]
  dataset_y_pred = y_pred.iloc[dataset_df_test.index]

Until here,  I got it, here what are we trying to do?
y_test and y_pred are numpy arrays now after fit&predict, they are not working for iloc

Comment: Good catch. You are right that **y_pred** is NumPy array. **y_test** is still pd.DataFrame there. I removed iloc  for y_pred. You just subscript array with set of indices which you get from `dataset_df_test.index`.